# awk / sed how to add file with special characters to another file into certain line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have problem as written in the subject.
The file under path /root/filetoadd has special characters as * < > / and new lines. The file has around 20 lines.

I want to add this file to another file under specific line.

Here it is what I did unlit now.

```
linenumber=`awk -v line='<xyz *>' '$0 == line {print NR}' /etc/folders/filewithsomedata`  
(this gives me line 162 thats correct, there I want to place another file) 
content=`cat /root/filetoadd`
sed -i "${linenumber} i \ ${content}" /etc/folders/filewithsomedata
```

The last line is giving me errors because how I mentioned above file contains special characters and new lines. Do you know how to add this file to keep original content with all those new lines and characters?

Comment: please put together and 30 char sample of your insert file and add it, and a very small sample "file to be added to". Don't make us guess what are the special chars, please ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Does `sed -r '/^<xyz *>$/{r /root/filetoadd;N}' /etc/folders/filewithsomedata` work?

Comment: You can get all the lines before a pattern with `grep -B 999 pattern file` and all the lines after a pattern with `grep -A 999 pattern file` and you can get the bit you want in the middle with `cat middlefile`, so try `{ grep -B 999 ... ; cat middlefile ; grep -A 999 ... ; } > newFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this far too complicated. You never need sed when you're using awk. Just do this:

```
awk -v line='<xyz *>' '
NR==FNR { add = add $0 ORS; next }
{ print }
$0 == line { printf "%s", add }
' /root/filetoadd /etc/folders/filewithsomedata > tmp &&
mv tmp /etc/folders/filewithsomedata
```

Comment: ok so how it's exactly working and how to add this file above '<xyz *>' ?

Comment: `NR==FNR` is a condition that's only true when the first file (/etc/filetoadd/) is being read and the associated action `add = add $0 ORS` is just adding 1 line at a time to the variable `add`. `next` means "go onto the next line of input". So when we get to `{ print }` the whole of the first file has been saved in the variable `add`. The `{print}` prints every line of the 2nd file, and the $0 == line etc. just prints the contents of add when appropriate. Just swap the order of `{ print }` and `$0 == line { printf "%s", add }` to print `add` before rather than after the line containing `line`.